# Version of Tanaka's Formula outside Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales

Given a Brownian Motion $B = \lbrace B_t, t \geq 0\rbrace$, Tanaka's Formula provides a decomposition of the submartingale process $|B|$
given by
$$|B_t| = \int_0^t sgn(B_s) dB_s +L_0^B(t)$$

where $L_0^B$ is the local time of $B$ at zero.

Are there any other processes which have a similar decomposition? That is, what processes $X$ would satisfy

$$|X_t| = \int_0^t sgn(X_s) dX_s +L_0^X(t)$$

where $L_0^X$ is the local time of $X$ at zero.

I am looking at the proof of Tanaka's formula to see if $B$ can easily be replaced by any martingale or semimartingale. However, as a beginner student in Stochastic Processes, I still cannot fully grasp the proof. However, I am posting this question as a curious student who wants to know the answer to the above question.

Thank you to anyone who can shed light on this.

Comment: This paper generalises the Tanaka formula to symmetric Levy processes: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0501182 . I would also suggest looking into the Doob decomposition theorem.

Comment: thanks for your answer. will look on it. also, thanks for the correction @AngelaRichardson

Comment: The Tanaka formula is true for continuous semimartingales (a result due to P.A. Meyer).  If memory serves you can find a discussion in the book of Revuz & Yor.